# Assigning random value for categories in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

```
Name        Week
Google      1
Google      1
Amazon      1
Tesla       1
Tesla       1
Google      2
Google      2
Tesla       2
Tesla       2
Uber        3
Uber        3
```

I am trying to create a new column `value` which would be a random integer between `x` an `y` for combinations of `Name` and `Week` like so:

```
Name        Week        Value
Google      1           100
Google      1           100
Amazon      1           150
Tesla       1           170
Tesla       1           170
Google      2           250
Google      2           250
Tesla       2           157
Tesla       2           157
Uber        3           500
Uber        3           500
```

Where the same value is assigned for the combination of `Name` and `Week`.

I tried:

```
def random_group_int(df_):
    
    week = df_.week_no
    supplier = df_.sm_supp_name

    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(df.Week.unique(), df.Name.unique()))

    rand_values_dict_by_combination = {combination: np.random.randint(100,200) for combination in combinations}

    # return value by the combination on the line
    # don't know how to do that
```

And I feel like this is not the best approach. I also tried:

```
df_rand = df.groupby(['Name','Week']).count()
df_rand['Value'] = df_rand['Week'].apply(lambda x : np.random.randint(100,200))
df_rand.reset_index(inplace = True)
df.merge(df_rand[['Value', 'Name', 'Week']], left_on = ['Name', 'Week'], right_on = ['Name', 'Week'], how = 'left')
```

Which does work but again, I am not sure if that's the approach I should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and generate a random value in the transform:

```
import random
x, y = 100, 200
df['Value'] = (df.groupby(['Name', 'Week'])['Name'] # the column doesn't matter
                 .transform(lambda _: random.randint(x, y))
               )
```

example output:

```
      Name  Week  Value
0   Google     1    153
1   Google     1    153
2   Amazon     1    196
3    Tesla     1    198
4    Tesla     1    198
5   Google     2    122
6   Google     2    122
7    Tesla     2    180
8    Tesla     2    180
9     Uber     3    106
10    Uber     3    106
```

Comment: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 75203 elements, new values have 78087 elements` is what I get on my `df` but this approach looks the best, do you think this error is because of `NaN`s?

Comment: Yes, could be, try to add `dropna=False` as parameter of `groupby`, otherwise try to provide an example that reproduces the error

Comment: Then the numbers switch places between whats expected and the axis.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your needs

```
s = df.drop_duplicates()
s['random_int'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(s), 1))
df_merge = pd.merge(df, s, how = 'left')
df_merge
```

Comment: I don't recommend this method. It would trigger a SettingWithCopyWarning as the first command produces a view, or you would need to use `df.drop_duplicates().copy()`. Also dropping the duplicates to then merge seems a bit a waste of CPU ;)

Comment: Not all of us think like a computer like you do skynet! Thank you though, but I thought I've seen you do things similar to this where you will get a df of desired results then join it back to the original.

Comment: Could be, I don't always do smart things :p (or maybe it was a different context?)

Comment: Oh it was certainly a different context, next time I see it i'll ask you why using it in the situation was better than this one!